# Roam between different access points

Tags: android, wifi, roaming

I'm working on a android application to make a phone call via WiFi.
It is working fine, but when I move in the building and the phone has to make a connection with a new access point because the signal gets to weak I lose connection for a second or two.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think is to simulate a telephone "hold" signal when you detect a stronger signal you want to hop to. Otherwise, even if you manage to make the swap smoothly, the other side would probably still see it as a disconnection and hang up their end. There will still be a brief pause while it's on hold and swapping, but it's better than a disconnect. Maybe add a tone to warn you when it's about to put it on hold?

Good luck, by the way.  don't know of a telephony app that does this, but it seems incredibly useful. Of course, there may be a reason they don't.